# Material Design Web DataTable cell text wrap

Tags: components, material-design, word-wrap

I am using the Material Design DataTable component, [here](https://material.io/components/data-tables/web#using-data-tables)

I am unable to make long text wrap.

The default table-layout is 'fixed'

I have set the table width to 100%

I have added the below css for the table cell I want to wrap text:

```
td.note {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-overflow: initial; // default is ellipsis
}
```

The long text is simply cut off at the boundary of the cell and does not wrap on to new lines.

Has anyone got this to work with the DataTable compoeent?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone encountering the same issue, the problem was the class .mdc-data-table__table which adds white-space: no-wrap to the table element